# Calculating Signal Loss (dB) Through Vias

Tags: pcb, rf, via, high-speed

Does anyone have any useful calculations or links to material covering good ways to calculate signal loss through vias?

What would be perfect is a graph with typical loss in dB over the range 1GHz to 10Ghz+

I'm calculating the total signal loss of some 10G SerDes traces, in order to work out the required pre-emphasis.

Comment: Don't you have access to some simulation software like Hyperlynx ? Because, doing computation "by hand" with this kind of frequency will result in a gross value. That's helpful if it's to help you choose a range of pre-emphasis, you can assimilated your via to a trace, with some kind of majoration. But if you want a precise value for your pre-emphasis, you need to use a simulation software.

Answer (score 2):

This free download might help: -

[image]

It certainly appears to tell you several things about vias at RF and it's free.

Comment: Very nice software, and completely free. Fantastic.

Comment: I use it, but be careful, it's not as accurate as a 2D/3D field solver.